# How do I render a 2D overlay with DirectX 9?

Tags: c++, 2d, directx, hud

I'm working in C++ with DirectX 9 on a 3D game, but I want a 2D overlay for rendering a HUD.

I've heard that I could use `D3DXMatrixOrthoLH`, but I'm very confused on how to use it. I'm more familiar with OpenGL, where I could simply switch between 3D and 2D by initiating the view.

How can I do this in DirectX 9?

**EDIT:**

I was able to achieve this like (partial psudocode):

But I have a good feeling this is not the right way to do it.

```
void render()
{
    beginscene();

    D3DXMATRIX matrix;
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matrix);

    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matrix, 0, 0, 0);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matrix);

    // Render 3D.

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matrix);

    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matrix);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matrix);

    D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterRH();
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matrix);

    // Render 2D.

    endscene();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I've decided to scratch DirectX and go back to good old OpenGL, which I'm much more familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this, is probably the [ID3DXSprite interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174249(v=vs.85).aspx).

> The `ID3DXSprite` interface provides a set of methods that simplify the process of drawing sprites using Microsoft Direct3D.
>
> The `ID3DXSprite` interface is obtained by calling the `D3DXCreateSprite(...)` function

This call requires a valid pointer to an `IDirect3DDevice9` object.

To use this interface, simply call `Draw` for each texture you want to be rendered, between a call to `Begin` and `End`. Since `Begin` will alter the device state, you should make sure your other rendering happens before `Begin`, or after `End`, which restores the previous state.

To rotate or scale a texture, you can create a matrix and pass it to `SetMatrix` before your `Draw` call.